# serialise nested unordered maps

Tags: c++, boost-serialization

I've got a variable with a declaration that looks like

```
boost::unordered_map< std::string, boost::unordered_map <long,int>, hashe::fnv_1a> _pl;
```

I need to serialise this to a file and and deserialise later. Should I just do a nested loop or can i do something ultracool with boost::serialisation? Any help pointing me towards nested declarations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define template function of serialization of each type. Boost serialization can be easily implemented for vectors and maps. Simply define serialize function for each type.

```
template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive& ar,unsigned int version)
```

For more help see some examples:
[Boost Serialization Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html)